# Expose all Drupal Webform submissions data in one view?

Tags: webforms, forms

I'm trying expose all Drupal [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) submissions data in a single view with a contextual filter.

I have tried the [Webforms MySQL Views module](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_mysql_views), and I think that is exactly what I am after, except you have to do the same process for every form (e.g. http://vimeo.com/18701843 & https://www.drupal.org/node/1658784).

My website allows for users to create their own webform which means there could be thousands of them that I'd have to create the MySQL View for and that's not really feasible.

Is there a way to either automate this, or create one view for all webforms?